# problems with library vue-sweetalert in my project, not load the styles

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-sweetalert2

I have the next problem.
I'm using vue-sweetalert in my project (electron-vue)
So I import the library in main.js but is not load the styles:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7bqi.png)

I have this in my main, I have another directory to import the library vue-sweetalert
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juwpt.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyLqR.png)

have someone happened the same problem? Help me please.

- I need help I not have time

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.